# Change res/string programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have an app that i want to make in three languages.Now i created 3 string resources with different languages and my whole app references the 1st one. is it possible to reference the other 2 on an event trigger? Can anyone explain in details please. I heard about locale object but im not very sure how it works

Comment: I have the feeling you didn't understand the concept of localization yet. Read the documentation thoroughly: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can localize your strings by using locale-specific resource directories?

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-de-rCH/strings.xml
res/values-de-rAT/strings.xml
```

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#using-framework for more details.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this at run time on event..or click event use this code

```
private void changeLanguage(String lang) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Configuration conf = getApplicationContext().getResources()
            .getConfiguration();
    conf.setToDefaults();
    ///
    if (conf.locale == null)
        conf.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    //////
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("english")) {
        conf.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    } else if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("chinese")) {
        conf.locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
    }

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources resources = new Resources(
            getApplicationContext().getAssets(), metrics, conf);
     /* get localized string */
     String str = resources.getString(R.string.back);
     Log.i("mini", "Chinese:" + str);

}
```